# Por que no me funciona este codigo de jquery para DataTable en Asp.Net Mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net, mvc, datatables

Estoy tratando de mostrar los datos en formato DataTable y no me función aquí le paso el código.

```js
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GetData";
}

<h2>Employee CRUD Operations</h2>

<table id="employeeTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>id_contrato</th>
            <th>responsable</th>
            <th>titulo</th>
            <th>descripcion</th>
            <th>inicio</th>
            <th>vigencia</th>
            <th>monto</th>
            @*<th>Description</th>
            <th>Description</th>*@
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>


<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


@section scripts{
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>

 
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            dataTable = $("#employeeTable").DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    "url":"/contratos_data/GetData",
                    "type": "GET",
                    "datatype": "Json"
                },

                "columns": [
                    { data: "id_contrato" },
                    { data: "responsable" },
                    { data: "titulo" },
                    { data: "descripcion" },
                    { data: "inicio" },
                    { data: "vigencia" }, 
                    { data: "monto" }
                    //{ "data": "Categorycontract.Description" },
                    //{ "data": "Departament.Description" }
                ]
                //"serverSide": "true",
                //"order":[0,"asc"]
                 });
            });
    </script>

}
```

```html
public JsonResult GetData()
        {
            using (Contratos_JuridicaContext db = new Contratos_JuridicaContext())
            {
                //List<contratos_data> contra = db.contratos_data.ToList<contratos_data>();
                var contra = db.contratos_data.ToList();
                return Json(new { data = contra }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor cambia las imágenes por texto. ¿Has visto en la consola del navegador si obtienes algún error?

Comment: no, simplemente sale los datos, pero no en la tabla como debería de ser

Comment: Estás dandole a la tabla un json, pero lo que necesita es que le cargues un arrray

Comment: como hago eso Aaron Romero?

Answer (score 0):

Después del ultimo `<th>` pon otro vacio ejemplo:

```
      <tr>
        <th>id_contrato</th>
        <th>responsable</th>
        <th>titulo</th>
        <th>descripcion</th>
        <th>inicio</th>
        <th>vigencia</th>
        <th>monto</th>           
        <th></th>
      </tr>
```

ese `<th>` vacio datatable lo utiliza para el cuadro de búsqueda y si no está definido a veces no se muestra la tabla. Tampoco veo definido el `<tbody>`

Comment: ya arregle esa parte, pero el problema es que los datos me cargan pero no en la tabla sino que lo hace sin formato como se muestra en la imagen